# Using C#, what is the best logic to determine the "left" location of a object on a page so its horizontally evenly distributed?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, layout

I am trying to  dynamically layout a bunch of squares on a surface (could be winform app, web page, etc) and I am trying to figure out a function where

**Given:**
1. The page has a fixed width
2. The square has a fixed width

**Input**: The input into the function is:

```
   The number of squares
```

**Output**: The output is an array that has:

```
  the "left" location of each square to lay them out so they are equally spaced out horizontally on the page.
```

My program is in C# but I guess there are two parts of the question

1. What i guess is more of a math question that then could be solved in any programming language
2. The easiest way to code that in C#.

I am more focused on #1 right now as i presume once the logic could be defined then #2 might be very simple but I still tagged the question as C# as well just because that is what my program is in.

Here is an example:

Lets say the surface has a width of 800 pixels.  The square is 50 pixels wide

I am looking for some code that, given the number of squares required, it tells me where the left pixel should be

so for example, if I only have one square, the left location would be 375 because it would be

```
  (TOTAL WIDTH OF PAGE / 2) -  (WIDTH OF SQUARE / 2)

  (800 /2) - (50/2) or 400 - 25 - 375
```

if i put the left location of the square at 375 then it would be perfectly centered on the page

if I had two squares it would be

```
First one:

  (TOTAL WIDTH OF PAGE / 4) -  (WIDTH OF SQUARE / 2)

  ((800 / 4) * 1) - (50/2) or 200 - 25 - 175

Second One:

  ((800 / 4) * 3) - (50/2) or 600 - 25 - 575
```

if i had three squares, it would be  175, 375, 575

I am trying to see if there is a more generalized function that i can create out of this (versus having hard coded logic for each number of squares) so that would work for any number of squares (the most i would realistically have would be 10 but I am trying not to hard code it.  I know that if I have more than 16 squares then they won't fix on a page horizontally even if they are side by side but that is fine as I don't see ever getting to that point.

Comment: But you already have your logic... you just demonstrated in your question. Or are you trying to say, that the logic you came up with is wrong? If so, explain why you think it is wrong...

Comment: I have hard coded logic for examples where there are 1, 2 or 3 items but I am trying to generalize it into a function

Comment: In case of `n>1` shouldn't it be that first square is left aligned (has `0` coordinate) and last square is right aligned (has `750` coordinate)?

Comment: @Ulugbek Umirov - no, I want to distribute the items as "centered" and evenly on the page

Comment: What stops you from doing that and using variables for the, errm..., numbers which are variable in your logic/equation?

Comment: Do you see generalized logic here as the formula is different for my different use cases. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to calculate it would be to find out how much space is left over, and then divide that by the total number of squares + 1

`(pageWidth - totalSquareWidth) / (numberOfSquares + 1)`

So if the page is 800px, and there are 3 x 50px, squares each space would be

`(800 - 150) / (3 + 1) = 162.5`

Then to calculate the positions, you just need to add up the spaces + all the preceding squares

`squareNumber * space + ((squareNumber -1) * squareSize)`

And some code to help (it's java but it should be easy enough to adapt)

```
public int[] getSquarePositions(int numberOfSquares) 
{
    int[] positions = new int[numberOfSquares];
    int pageWidth = 800;     
    int squareSize = 50;
    int space = (pageWidth - (squareSize * numberOfSquares)) / (numberOfSquares + 1);

    for (int x = 0; x < positions.length; x++)
    {
        positions[x] = (x + 1) * space + (x * squareSize);
    }

    return positions;
}
```

Comment: This gives you the location of n squares? (n = numberOfSquares)

Comment: but if i had one square, your formula would produce (800 - (50 / (1+1)) or 800 - 25 = 775 which isn't the correct logic as one square should return 375

Comment: 800 - 50 = 750, divided by 2 = 375. It should be (800 - 50)/(1+1)